# Excel VBA error 13 type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

i have recently started working on VBA and i have run into a problem which i can't fix

the macro i have created has to copy a block of text, it gets triggerd by a checked checkbox, also if the checkbox is unchecked the textblok had to dis aperear

this is he code

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

    If Sheets("Blad1").CheckBox1.Value = True Then Sheets("Blad3").Range("C2").Value = 1
    If Sheets("Blad1").CheckBox1.Value = False Then Sheets("Blad3").Range("C2").Value = 0

    If Sheets("Blad3").Range("C2").Value = 1 Then 
       Sheets("Blad1").Range("B7:B15").Value.Copy Destination = Sheets("Blad2").Range("A1:B8").Value
    End If

    If Sheets("Blad3").Range("C2").Value = 0 Then
    End If

    Application.Goto Worksheets("Blad2").[A1:A9], True
    Range("A1:A9").Clear

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your code just needs tiding up a bit. Try this:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

If Sheets("Blad1").CheckBox1.Value = True Then 
    Sheets("Blad3").Range("C2").Value = 1
Else
    Sheets("Blad3").Range("C2").Value = 0
End IF


If Sheets("Blad3").Range("C2").Value = 1 Then
  Sheets("Blad1").Range("B7:B15").Copy 
  Sheets("Blad2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlValues
Else
  Sheets("Blad2").Range("A1:A9").Clear
End If

End Sub
```